# Find Bifurcation/Splitting Point of two 3D Curves

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, intersection, curve

I have the coordinates of curves in 3D space (point curve). The pairs of these curves lie in each other or have pretty much the same coordinates for a while until they branch off. I want to find the point where the two curves branch off of each other or the best estimate of that point.

I tried to find the closest distance along the points of the two curves and then look when this distance is higher than a certain small threshold which I estimated experimentally. This works, however, only roughly to find the splitting point and differs from pair to pair of my curves.

I guess a good solution would be to interpolate both point curves with (cubic) splines with scipy or splipy and then calculate the (last) intersection point of these two curves. I don't know how to do that though.

[Example picture of two point curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqN0n.png)

[Splitting Point I am searching for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLgO9.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does your approach differ between curve pairs because you need to adapt the threshold? And why do you only get a rough solution? Doesn't sound too bad in my opinion. I advise against the interpolation strategy. The point you are looking for is not necessarily an intersection point and splines do not really give you any benefit here - they just make it more complicated.